# DASK with local files on WORKER systems

Tags: worker, file-sharing, dask

I am working with mutiple systems as workers. 
Each worker system has a part of the data locally stored. And I want the computation done by each worker on its respective file only.

I have tried using :

#### distributed.scheduler.decide_worker()

#### send_task_to_worker(worker, key)

but I could not automate assigning the task for each file.

Also, is there anyway I can access local files of the worker? Using tcp address, I only have access to a temp folder of the worker created for dask.

Comment: Do you know a priori which files are on which worker machines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can target computations to run on certain workers using the `workers=` keyword to the various methods on the client.  See http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/locality.html#user-control for more information.

You might run a function on each of your workers that tells you which files are present:

```
>>> client.run(os.listdir, my_directory)
{'192.168.0.1:52523': ['myfile1.dat', 'myfile2.dat'],
 '192.168.0.2:4244': ['myfile3.dat'],
 '192.168.0.3:5515': ['myfile4.dat', 'myfile5.dat']}
```

You might then submit computations to run on those workers specifically.

```
future = client.submit(load, 'myfile1.dat', workers='192.168.0.1:52523')
```

If you are using dask.delayed you can also pass `workers=` to the `persist method.  See http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/locality.html#user-control for more information